# ASP.Net Web Handler UNC vs. File Path

Tags: asp.net, httphandler

I have a Web Handler that I'm using to read a file and then stream it out to the client.  This works fine if i use the file path on the local drive:
  D:\Path\To\My\File.flv

If I use a sharename, however:
  \ServerName\ShareName\File.flv

I get a "Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password."

The share is open to everyone, full control.

I have impersonation enabled and have the following in my handler:

```
context.Response.Write("Context User: " + ((WindowsIdentity)context.User.Identity).Name + "<br />");
context.Response.Write("Windows Identity: " + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name + "<br />");
```

When I configure the IIS application to run as with anonymous access using a specific account, I get the following

Context User:
Windows Identity: SpecificAccount

When I configure IIS to not use anonymous access, but use windows authentication, I get

Context User: MyAccount
Windows Identity: MyAccount

It does not change the error message for the share vs nonshare.

I  find this webpage regarding Web Handlers and impersonation: 
  http://weblogs.asp.net/drnetjes/archive/2005/06/06/410508.aspx

but, I'm not exactly sure how to implement that, or, if it would even solve the issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does `NETWORK SERVICE` id has access to the file and it's DIR hirarchy?

Comment: it does now, didn't help.. ):

Comment: have you given permission recursively (I mean DIR->subdir->leaf (file))? Is currently anonymous access denied?

Comment: Yes... I just rechecked to make sure.  and, like I said, I have everyone with full control.  And, it works fine if I access the same file through the directory structure.. it's just the UNC that fails.

Comment: What identity is the app pool running under? Make sure the app pool identity has access to the share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gaah... I hate answering my own questions, but here's what the problem was:

The share and file permissions were set properly.  This is an old windows 2003 machine and when I use a new application pool (which I did with this particular application), I always have a problem with permissions.

The solutions was (facepalm) reboot the server.

I'm sorry for all the braincells that the 60 some odd people wasted on this.

Thanks again for all your help.

Stupid IIS... Stupid Windows 2003... must rebuild server someday

Comment: Recycling that application pool should be enough instead of rebooting.

Comment: You'd think so, but it wasn't.. It has to do with something funky that I haven't been able to pin down with IIS.  An added benefit is that if I try to move an exiting application from one version of .Net to another, IIS gets grumpy and will shut down.  Then it wont come back up unless I reboot.  Even if i kill off the processes.  The server needs to be rebuilt.  I have a 2k8 box that I might have to migrate to sooner than later.

Comment: no need to reboot server (or shouldn't be) just Click Start->Run then type `iisreset` then punch the enter key as hard as you like to restart IIS.  Saved me a million headaches.

Comment: @Rob @Merlin changing an existing application's ASP.NET version in IIS Manager runs `aspnet_regiis -s`... and therefore always results in an `iisreset`. I use a customized version of the script here to change the ASP.Net version of one app without disturbing the others: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jorman/archive/2006/04/14/576605.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In your above post, it's simple, but you put `\ServerName\ShareName\File.flv`

shouldn't it be `\\ServerName\ShareName\File.flv`

worst case, you can use `file://ServerName/ShareName/File.flv`, but note that for local files you should use the shorthand `file:///C:/path/File.flv`. (see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme#Windows))

Comment: you were right.. I had \ accidentally.. it was actually \\ in my code.  I tried the file:// and file:///, but that doesn't work with System.IO.StreamReader (which is the actual reason for this whole thing)